# I literally copy and pasted a jquery code and it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I literally copy and pasted a jquery code and it does not work. I can never, for some reason, make jquery work. I dont know if there are any requierments to be able to use jquery. I got this code from a site and it works there but it does not work when i make a html file and open it. It just displays the text.

The code below is for making tabs with the text.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
          });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: did you check it with html file ? without  server ?

Comment: If you're running this on your local machine you will need to include the protocol on the include URLS, eg `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, it worked!

Comment: Step 1) Learn the fundamentals of the technology you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you're loading your page from a local file, not a webserver. Since you left out the URL scheme in the `<link>` and `<script>` tags, it will try to use the same scheme as the file that contains them, so it will try to read from a local file rather than the network. Add the `http:` prefix to the URLs to fix this:

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You could also use `https:` instead of `http:` for these, to use secure connections to the CDN.

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @MoLow Please read my comment to you below the other answer.

Comment: Also, if you're page is serving up content from HTTPS, you jQuery's CDN also includes `https://` versions of their libraries. So `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` for example.

Comment: @romellem If his page was coming from a server, the original protocol-relative URLs would have worked.

Comment: @Barmar True. Still, knowing that jQuery serves files over SSL as well may be useful.

Comment: I've added that to my answer. But I can't think of why I would use SSL for them if I didn't need to match the protocol of the calling page.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, since it doesn't just show how to fix it, but also explains what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading page without a web server, then change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Otherwise it will take file:// as protocol when you directly open file on browser, Since relative path is given. In these cases you have to specify http:// or https:// protocol.

Comment: wrong!! read this: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @MoLow That only works if you're loading the original page using HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: If you're loading from a local file, the protocol-relative URL will be `file://code.jquery.com/...`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, that might be an issue. correct

Comment: @MoLow it says about the file hosted in a server. Otherwise you need to specify the protocol

Comment: @MohammedSafeer it worked! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Alexis Then mark as answer